# How to avoid selection of rows of parents that don't have a child, if they have children in other rows?

Tags: sql, database, subquery, amazon-redshift, sql-except

I want to avoid selecting the cases where there is a blank child, but only where a parent-child relationship already exists. So in this example, A-D would stay but the empty rows with A should get removed. As C doesn't have any children in any row, it will remain.

Input:

```
parent     child
A          D
A
A
B          E
B          F
C
```

Desired Output:

```
parent     child
A          D
B          E
B          F
C
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT parent, child
FROM my_table
WHERE child NOT NULL
EXCEPT 
SELECT parent, child
FROM my_table
-- condition to check existing relationships if they exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe use a query like below. this uses exists keyword to check presence of any other not null child

```
SELECT parent, child
FROM my_table t
WHERE child is NOT NULL
OR NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM my_table p Where p.parent=t.parent and p.child is Not null
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially 2 queries so we can join them with `UNION ALL`

- the first query is where there is a child `child is not null`
- the second query is where the number of children is 0. By default COUNT() does not include null values. We also use `GROUP BY` which means that duplicate rows will be combined.

```
SELECT parent, child FROM t
WHERE child IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT parent, null FROM t
GROUP BY parent
HAVING COUNT(child) = 0;
```

> ```
> parent | child
> :----- | :----
> A      | D    
> B      | E    
> B      | F    
> C      | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ffbcf7422c34303f327ef9a562856b4f)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use two queries with `UNION ALL` one is getting result by `child IS NOT NULL` another is getting result by condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT parent,child
FROM my_table
WHERE child IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT parent,child
FROM my_table
GROUP BY parent,child
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN child IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 1
```

or another way you might make a trick let condition in `HAVING` to make it simple.

```
SELECT parent,child
FROM my_table
GROUP BY parent,child
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN child IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 1 OR child IS NOT NULL
```